# Notepad++: Execution without restarting pdf-reader Sumatra

Tags: pdf, nppexec

I compile ConTeXt out of NP++ with the following command in the Execution-Plugin:

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
context.exe "filename.tex" --synctex=1
taskkill /im SumatraPDF.exe
C:\somedirectory\sumatra.bat "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\filename.pdf"
```

This command compiles the context-file and opens it in the PDF-reader Sumatra. As you see, I close the reader ("taskkill") and restart it again with every compile.

But that is not necessary, Sumatra updates the pdf-file by its own. So how to change the command, such that the reader will be only started, if it is not already started?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to remove the line

```
taskkill /im SumatraPDF.exe
```

and call something like this (the reuse-instance operator should do this quite well)

```
C:\somedirectory\sumatra.bat "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\filename.pdf" -reuse-instance
```

at least this works for my current LaTeX setup with a quite similiar method.

This is a tutorial i used to get my NP++ working with MikTex
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows

Comment: Does not work here, simply opens just another instance of sumatra.

Comment: What is your sumatra.bat doing? why aren't you using the SumatraPDF.exe instead?

can you assure that -reuse-instance isn't working for you by using the commandline?